# Can Google analytics be used for an old web app?

Tags: web-applications, google-analytics

I have heard about google analytics ad currently reading up and researching it. My company has a really old web app that's being retired but before it does I would like to pull some statistical information on it. The application was developed on a struts 1.1 framework with a hibernate persistence layer (around 2007ish I think).
Since it's not a customer serving site per se and there's no advertising involved. I'd just like to track the busiest functional part(s) of the web app.
Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just use the server log?

Comment: It's a badly coded app with too much needless data dumped into the server logs. + the boss thinks GA can be used to profile (performance) the web app.

Comment: The access log, not log4j/etc. log, I meant.

Comment: That's a thought. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Enabling google analytics is just a question of adding a piece of javascript to all the pages. Hopefully your web app has some template that you can put this piece of javascript into, so that it is emitted on all pages.

Comment: I wish I were that lucky, but no it doesn't. What about generated pages? I also read that "Data about the page visit is collected and sent to the Analytics server through a list of parameters attached to a single-pixel image request" does this mean that user personal info and data on the pages will be sent aswell?